# undefined reference to `main' - collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, reference, undefined, collect

I am trying to compile in a UNIX environment and keep receiving this error. However, all I have is the main function in the file? Any ideas? This is the ONLY code I have since I was having the error in a different file and decided to test the compilation with JUST the main function if a header file is included. I removed the include statement for the headerfile and it compiles just fine. I have tried gcc filename headfilename, just to see if it would make a difference, however, it does not. The header file is located in the same folder.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
#include "TriePrediction.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

This is the exact error I am getting:

```
In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compiling with the following line: gcc TriePrediction.c

I have also tried:

```
gcc TriePrediction.c TriePrediction.h
```

The main function is located in TriePrediction.c

This is the header file:

NOTE: I removed the places I set up the functions for compilation reasons in the file so I know that is wrong , however, I did so to see if that was messing up the compiling with the undefined reference error.

```
#ifndef __TRIE_PREDICTION_H
#define __TRIE_PREDICTION_H

#define MAX_WORDS_PER_LINE 30
#define MAX_CHARACTERS_PER_WORD 1023

// This directive renames your main() function, which then gives my test cases
// a choice: they can either call your main() function (using this new function
// name), or they can call individual functions from your code and bypass your
// main() function altogether. THIS IS FANCY.
#define main demoted_main

typedef struct TrieNode
{
    // number of times this string occurs in the corpus
    int count;

    // 26 TrieNode pointers, one for each letter of the alphabet
    struct TrieNode *children[26];

    // the co-occurrence subtrie for this string
    struct TrieNode *subtrie;
} TrieNode;


// Functional Prototypes

TrieNode *buildTrie(char *filename);

TrieNode *destroyTrie(TrieNode *root);

TrieNode *getNode(TrieNode *root, char *str);

void getMostFrequentWord(TrieNode *root, char *str);

int containsWord(TrieNode *root, char *str);

int prefixCount(TrieNode *root, char *str);

double difficultyRating(void);

double hoursSpent(void);

#endif
```

Comment: Please show your exact build command line.

Comment: Are there any macros that redefine `main` in the troublesome header file?

Comment: @kaylum updated

Comment: @InternetAussie There is something that says #define main demoted_main, would that do that? It was given to me by an instructor to use in functions. Not exactly sure what that line does -- would that make a difference?

Comment: @starlight If including that header file makes the compilation fail, then yes. The problem would lie there.

Comment: Not quite sure why the question got down rated, however, I added the header file.

Comment: There must be more instructions from your teaching staff. They obviously want to be the ones to provide `main` in their test harness. So there must be some code or object file they want you to link in. Alternatively, they may want you to test with your own test harness which simluates their one by providing a `main` that calls `demoted_main`. These are not questions we can answer without the full assignment spec.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you, I'll look through the files again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header function is defining `main` to be `demoted_main` this means that your program does not have a main function and cannot be linked with gcc. In order to have your program link correctly you will have to remove that line. You could also use linker options to use `demoted_main` as your entry point. This is possible with `gcc -o TriePrediction.c TriePrediction.h -Wl,-edemoted_main -nostartfiles` but not recommended.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense!